# How to detect DOM changes using a class Selector Directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, selector, angular2-directives

Create a directive that applied certain functionality to all the elements that had the "active" class.
However, if at run time it added the "active" class to an existing DOM element, the functionality of the directive was not applied to it.

```
import { Directive, Renderer2, ElementRef, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: '.active'
})
export class RemoveActivesDirective implements OnInit {
  el: any;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.el = element.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) removeActives() {
    console.log('Eliminando elemento', event);
    this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.el).remove();
  }


}
```

How can I tell the board that there have been changes in the html?
How can I make the directive work with the elements that acquire the class at run time?

Thanks

Comment: Using this should be a last resort. Use templating and data-binding provided by Angular instead.   Relying on direct DOM access creates tight coupling between your application and rendering layers which will make it impossible to separate the two and deploy your application into a web worker.